# How can I get json collected data from child to parent component in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have results data in child component but I should bring it to main component.

Main Component in Parent, so each time I click the button, the result should be gathered in main app

```
 <button @click="showFinalResult">Click me</button>
```

Child component data here and I just need to show results in json format in parent, the results are input results

```
 results: [],
```

Comment: does this help ~ https://forum.vuejs.org/t/trying-to-pass-json-data-from-child-to-parent-and-control-it-from-parent/42216/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can emit event for child for sending data:

```js
Vue.component('Child', {
  template: `
    <div class="">
      
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      results: [1,2,3]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$emit('update', this.results);
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      res: [],
      show: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getResult(res) {
      this.res = res
    },
    showResults() {
      this.show = !this.show
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button @click="showResults">Click me</button>
  <p v-if="show">{{ res }}</p>
  <child @update="getResult" />
</div>
```

Comment: you code is working as I expected but I need button in parent element. Can you please modify your code a bit?

Comment: @Davis Vue.js Developer hey mate, check now pls, I updated my answer